# One or more types required to compile a dynamic expression cannot be found. Are you missing a reference?

Tags: c#, json, dynamic, foreach

```
dynamic dynObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonString);
                var sOffers = dynObj.b2b;
                //string sCoupons = dynObj;

                System.Data.DataTable dtPromotions = new System.Data.DataTable();
                dtPromotions.Columns.Add("ctin", typeof(string));
                dtPromotions.Columns.Add("inv", typeof(string));
                dtPromotions.Columns.Add("val", typeof(double));
                dtPromotions.Columns.Add("idt", typeof(DateTime));
                dtPromotions.Columns.Add("txval", typeof(double));
                dtPromotions.Columns.Add("camt", typeof(double));

                foreach (var cou in sOffers)
                {
                    string cou1 = Convert.ToString(cou);
                    string[] RowData = Regex.Split(cou1.Replace
                    ("{", "").Replace("}", ""), ",");
                    DataRow nr = dtPromotions.NewRow();
                    foreach (string rowData in RowData)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            int idx = rowData.IndexOf(":");
                            string RowColumns = rowData.Substring
                            (0, idx - 1).Replace("\"", "").Trim();
                            string RowDataString = rowData.Substring
                            (idx + 1).Replace("\"", "");
                            nr[RowColumns] = RowDataString;
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            continue;
                        }
                    }
                    dtPromotions.Rows.Add(nr);
```

it is give me error

One or more types required to compile a dynamic expression cannot be found. Are you missing a reference?

foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'System.Collections.IEnumerable' because 'System.Collections.IEnumerable' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'

json data

```
{
```

"gstin": "24BIMPM5816M1ZS",
  "fp": "072017",
  "b2b": [
    {
      "ctin": "24AUNPP1970D1ZL",
      "cfs": "Y",
      "cname": null,
      "inv": [
        {
          "val": 135450,
          "itms": [
            {
              "num": 1,
              "itm_det": {
                "samt": 3225,
                "rt": 5,
                "txval": 129000,
                "camt": 3225
              }
            }
          ],
          "inv_typ": "R",
          "pos": "24",
          "idt": "25-07-2017",
          "rchrg": "N",
          "inum": "8",
          "chksum": "226711c5f67483b9d7ebefed3bce124835d6fc6d5e2ba087f0438e9c3c8c7fe7"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "ctin": "24ADIPM3140N1ZH",
      "cfs": "Y",
      "cname": null,
      "inv": [
        {
          "val": 38932,
          "itms": [
            {
              "num": 1,
              "itm_det": {
                "samt": 926.95,
                "csamt": 0,
                "rt": 5,
                "txval": 37078.1,
                "camt": 926.95
              }
            }
          ],
          "inv_typ": "R",
          "pos": "24",
          "idt": "31-07-2017",
          "rchrg": "N",
          "inum": "50",
          "chksum": "c1fdd2c29c66639b4f68990b9da82c4c98ee893be5364dc77f78d1b125c51675"
        },
        {
          "val": 35964,
          "itms": [
            {
              "num": 1,
              "itm_det": {
                "samt": 856.29,
                "csamt": 0,
                "rt": 5,
                "txval": 34251.44,
                "camt": 856.29
              }
            }
          ],
          "inv_typ": "R",
          "pos": "24",
          "idt": "31-07-2017",
          "rchrg": "N",
          "inum": "51",
          "chksum": "34200dd2629cfa60e98984ea7e7b19febde6f7bfb8bdb159b01a4c05c42f8104"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "ctin": "24AOFPG1728Q1ZR",
      "cfs": "Y",
      "cname": null,
      "inv": [
        {
          "val": 19214,
          "itms": [
            {
              "num": 1,
              "itm_det": {
                "samt": 457.48,
                "csamt": 0,
                "rt": 5,
                "txval": 18299.28,
                "camt": 457.48
              }
            }
          ],
          "inv_typ": "R",
          "pos": "24",
          "idt": "29-07-2017",
          "rchrg": "N",
          "inum": "250/JB",
          "chksum": "477566683cd56262c513fd155d3975c8eec0f3efcb6fbf585ddd2b2e750ad763"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "ctin": "24AOYPG9615H1ZH",
      "cfs": "Y",
      "cname": null,
      "inv": [
        {
          "val": 36203,
          "itms": [
            {
              "num": 1,
              "itm_det": {
                "samt": 861.98,
                "csamt": 0,
                "rt": 5,
                "txval": 34479,
                "camt": 861.98
              }
            }
          ],
          "inv_typ": "R",
          "pos": "24",
          "idt": "28-07-2017",
          "rchrg": "N",
          "inum": "889",
          "chksum": "e6cb091f4f0c1839387661eee1c4bfac9e910a3352a6cbfcda478ba274f033f9"
        },
        {
          "val": 37951,
          "itms": [
            {
              "num": 1,
              "itm_det": {
                "samt": 903.58,
                "csamt": 0,
                "rt": 5,
                "txval": 36143,
                "camt": 903.58
              }
            }
          ],
          "inv_typ": "R",
          "pos": "24",
          "idt": "28-07-2017",
          "rchrg": "N",
          "inum": "890",
          "chksum": "5f6664344d01de699262efe59e87d1995a5a2ea518db0fb19d3224f24c913538"
        },
        {
          "val": 36780,
          "itms": [
            {
              "num": 1,
              "itm_det": {
                "samt": 875.7,
                "csamt": 0,
                "rt": 5,
                "txval": 35028,
                "camt": 875.7
              }
            }
          ],
          "inv_typ": "R",
          "pos": "24",
          "idt": "28-07-2017",
          "rchrg": "N",
          "inum": "891",
          "chksum": "ed396b6b2a3108456798cc231750440679f3982e944c9711dd2b4864943fcef4"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "ctin": "24AJLPB1935F1ZM",
      "cfs": "N",
      "cname": null,
      "inv": [
        {
          "val": 19735,
          "itms": [
            {
              "num": 1,
              "itm_det": {
                "samt": 1505.25,
                "csamt": 0,
                "rt": 18,
                "txval": 16725,
                "camt": 1505.25
              }
            }
          ],
          "inv_typ": "R",
          "pos": "24",
          "idt": "22-07-2017",
          "rchrg": "N",
          "inum": "138",
          "chksum": "30b0fb30d87dc3ccd79adfaabaed9ee0a75ef3a2cf5b9879062b2edcb2295518"
        },
        {
          "val": 19735,
          "itms": [
            {
              "num": 1,
              "itm_det": {
                "samt": 1505,
                "csamt": 0,
                "rt": 18,
                "txval": 16725,
                "camt": 1505
              }
            }
          ],
          "inv_typ": "R",
          "pos": "24",
          "idt": "22-07-2017",
          "rchrg": "N",
          "inum": "37",
          "chksum": "7855dbbbdd860e7e5d084f12d256e78590fce043e65b668782b2619d334f02ba"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "ctin": "24AALPW2456R1ZT",
      "cfs": "Y",
      "cname": null,
      "inv": [
        {
          "val": 26951,
          "itms": [
            {
              "num": 1,
              "itm_det": {
                "samt": 642,
                "csamt": 0,
                "rt": 5,
                "txval": 25667,
                "camt": 642,
                "iamt": 0
              }
            }
          ],
          "inv_typ": "R",
          "pos": "24",
          "idt": "21-07-2017",
          "rchrg": "N",
          "inum": "S16",
          "chksum": "ddefbaef08e47543c33ce57e9e9e5cbea3495861eebdc22c93cfc33984f86717"
        },
        {
          "val": 15293,
          "itms": [
            {
              "num": 1,
              "itm_det": {
                "samt": 364,
                "csamt": 0,
                "rt": 5,
                "txval": 14565,
                "camt": 364,
                "iamt": 0
              }
            }
          ],
          "inv_typ": "R",
          "pos": "24",
          "idt": "22-07-2017",
          "rchrg": "N",
          "inum": "S22",
          "chksum": "b55da96384b115b4e96f0026c25078fafed4715f7dcdaed8e1b85331129a8626"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "ctin": "24AGDPP0330R1ZB",
      "cfs": "Y",
      "cname": null,
      "inv": [
        {
          "val": 11973,
          "itms": [
            {
              "num": 1,
              "itm_det": {
                "samt": 641.4,
                "rt": 12,
                "txval": 10690,
                "camt": 641.4
              }
            }
          ],
          "inv_typ": "R",
          "pos": "24",
          "idt": "24-07-2017",
          "rchrg": "N",
          "inum": "13",
          "chksum": "24888b197ca21c9648daa71531e97795b49b10881fedb603a3e6d86a8619a4b4"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "ctin": "24ATBPS2711E1Z5",
      "cfs": "Y",
      "cname": null,
      "inv": [
        {
          "val": 1434,
          "itms": [
            {
              "num": 1,
              "itm_det": {
                "samt": 76.8,
                "csamt": 0,
                "rt": 12,
                "txval": 1280,
                "camt": 76.8
              }
            }
          ],
          "inv_typ": "R",
          "pos": "24",
          "idt": "31-07-2017",
          "rchrg": "N",
          "inum": "8",
          "chksum": "0e16d7ab009973084b2480d910763cea7458870aa1a38d5559cd7b746c8bb788"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "ctin": "24AUUPS3017K1Z6",
      "cfs": "Y",
      "cname": null,
      "inv": [
        {
          "val": 6811,
          "itms": [
            {
              "num": 1,
              "itm_det": {
                "samt": 162.18,
                "csamt": 0,
                "rt": 5,
                "txval": 6486.64,
                "camt": 162.18
              }
            }
          ],
          "inv_typ": "R",
          "pos": "24",
          "idt": "19-07-2017",
          "rchrg": "N",
          "inum": "G4",
          "chksum": "4d05c1a0526d55442e5dcb1ecb51d77a8448b17f8bfec843678821b82f21e490"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}

Comment: Could you show us your json data?

Comment: Are you sure that your dynObj.b2b data is an enumeration ?

Comment: you should convert ``jsonString`` to a concrete type ``JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>```.That serves for the loop